# Lost all databases in postgresql because of automatic recovery

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

**What actually Happend**:

Running windows 7 on my system and system was shutdown due to power failure. when system restarted, I opened PostgreSQL and all my databases were deleted.

I checked logs and there were some entries

> ```
> Database system was intrupted ; last known up at (dateTime)
> Database system was not properly shutdown; automatic recovery in progress
> Record with zero length at 0/C9B92168
> Redo is not required
> ```

Can anybody tell me how can i recover my databases, as I don't have restore point.

Comment: These messages are harmless, they cannot be connected with lost databases.

Comment: I am not expert of PostgreSql , may you please guide me where are my Databases are they in file system and not showing in catalog or really deleted or something else..

Comment: It's impossible to say with that little information. You should hire a PostgreSQL expert to look at your system, or you should restore your backup.

Comment: What do you mean with "opened Postgres"? Did the list of databases in pgAdmin go away? If yes, can you access the databases using `psql`? (e.g. `psql --list`)